# Calculating time it takes to request data from client to server - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, client-server

So the title says it all - however the methodology that I tried seems to not work, and I have no idea why.

```
 public static IEnumerator RetrieveCharacterData(string userid, Action<string> charSelectResponse)
 {
    WWWForm data = new WWWForm();
    data.AddField("userid", userid);

    // Send request to server
    WWW characterSelectRequest = new WWW(Helper.Constants.kCharacterSelectUrl, data);
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;

    while (!characterSelectRequest.isDone)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        Debug.Log(elapsedTime); // This prints in real time the correct data

        if (elapsedTime >= Helper.Constants.ConnectionTimeoutInterval)
        {
            Debug.Log("Server error: Connection has timed out.");
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    // This doesn't work - prints out garbage values
    Debug.Log(elapsedTime); 


    if (!characterSelectRequest.isDone || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(characterSelectRequest.error))
    {
        charSelectResponse.Invoke(null);
        yield break;
    }
    charSelectResponse.Invoke(characterSelectRequest.text);
}
```

- So after some edits this has got me the closest to what I want - however when I try and obtain the actual elapsedTime, it prints out garbage values.

Answer (score 2):

`if (Time.time - startTime >= Helper.Constants.ConnectionTimeoutInterval)`

That `>=` should be `<`.

Currently, you're stuck in that loop without yielding, until the request is done. It then skips over the next if block, and ends up executing the elapsedTime check on the same call, without ever yielding, resulting in zero time difference, as far as Unity's Time is concerned.

Comment: This is not the problem

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is actually the problem.+1  Although, you need to fix this to exit the function when timeout (ConnectionTimeoutInterval) has been reached. Your current answer does not do that. I think that's why had the if statement there.

Comment: My issue isn't the calculation, it's why the elasedTime comes out with a garbage value...